# Calculate resistance between 1 and 2

Tags: dc, resistance

I am preparing for an electrical engineering exam coming up and I got stuck on task C, where you have to determine the resistance between 1 and 2. How do you do that exactly?
I have already solved tasks a and b.

[image]

Well, I know you have to switch off all sources first and then determine the resistance, but somehow I can't see how I should redraw the circuit to see if it is a series or parallel circuit. I would be grateful for any tips.

Information about the circuit R=10 ohm
Uq=20V, Iq= 3A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve this is by solving the nodes' current equations.
First redraw the circuit, number the nodes and their voltages, then write the nodes' equations and solve \$R_{12} = x R = 10x \Omega\$, the resistance asked for.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTCtzM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The sum of currents *going into* every node is zero.

$$ \frac{U_1}{xR} + \frac{U_3-U_1}{R} + \frac{U_4-U_1}{3R} = 0 \\
   \frac{U_3}{3R} + \frac{U4}{R} + \frac{-U_1}{xR} = 0 \\
   \frac{U_1-U_3}{R} +\frac{U_4-U_3}{2R} + \frac{-U_3}{3R} = 0 \\
   \frac{U_1-U_4}{3R} + \frac{U_3-U_4}{2R} + \frac{-U4}{R} = 0
$$

Recognize that \$U_1\$ is the driving voltage and therefore has to end up at the right hand side of the equations.

$$ \begin{align}
  \frac{U_3}{R} + \frac{U_4}{3R} &= -\frac{U_1}{xR} + \frac{U_1}{R} + \frac{U_1}{3R} \\
  \frac{U_3}{3R} + \frac{U_4}{R} &= \frac{U_1}{xR} \\
  -\frac{U_3}{R} -\frac{U_3}{2R} - \frac{U_3}{3R} +\frac{U_4}{2R} &= -\frac{U_1}{R} \\
  \frac{U_3}{2R} -\frac{U_4}{3R} -\frac{U_4}{2R} -\frac{U_4}{R} &= - \frac{U_1}{3R}
   \end{align}
$$

Multiply the top \$2\$ equations with \$3xR\$ and the bottom \$2\$ with \$6R\$ to get

$$ \begin{align}
  3 x U_3 + x U_4 &= ( -3 + 3x + x ) U_1 \\
  x U_3 + 3 x U_4 &= 3 U_1 \\
  ( - 6 - 3 - 2 ) U_3 + 3 U_4 &= - 6 U_1 \\
  3 U_3 + ( - 2 - 3 - 6 ) U_4 &= - 2 U_1
   \end{align}
$$

and after regrouping

$$ \begin{align}
  3 x U_3 + x U_4 &= ( 4 x - 3 ) U_1 \\
  x U_3 + 3 x U_4 &= 3 U_1 \\
  11 U_3 - 3 U_4 &= 6 U_1 \\
  3 U_3 - 11 U_4 &= - 2 U_1
   \end{align}
$$

The top 2 equations give \$ -8xU_4 = (4x - 12) U_1 \$, or
$$ 2 U_4 = ( 3/x - 1 ) U_1 $$
and the lower 2 equations give \$ 112 U_4 = 40 U_1 \$, or
$$ 2 U_4 = \frac{40}{56} U_1 = \frac{5}{7} U_1 $$

Subracting those two equations which express \$U_4\$ in \$U_1\$ from each other, gives \$ 0 = (3/x - 1 - \frac{5}{7}) U_1 \$, or

$$ x = 2 - \frac{1}{4} $$

Hence the equivalent resistance between terminals \$ 1 \$ and \$ 2 \$ equals \$ R_{12} = 17.50 \Omega \$. (How exciting...)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have shorted out the voltage source and open-circuited the current source, you apply a new source to terminals 1 and 2. For convenience, apply a 1 volt source and, through analysis, the current that flows is the inverse of the resistance between nodes 1 and 2: -

[image]

> *I can't see how I should redraw the circuit to see if it is a series
> or parallel circuit*

That's because it doesn't consist of simple series or parallel combinations of resistors. You have to use circuit theories to determine the resistance.

**EDIT to help OP**: [star delta transform calculator](http://www.ambrnet.com/CalcElectric/Star2Delta/Star2Delta.htm) link: -

[image]

Or, just use [microcap](https://gotroot.ca/spectrum/www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.html): -

[image]

Looks like 17.5 Ω resistance to me.

Comment: I see a node where 3 resistors are connected. For simplifying the circuit, this could be a good starting point fpr a star-triangle-modification.

Comment: @exactly my thoughts.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But how can I solve it mathematically with formulas?

Comment: The 20 ohm and the two upper resistors can be turned from a star shape to a delta shape using a star-delta transform. This makes it fairly easy to solve. If you don't know how this works google is your friend and gives you all the conversion formula @Omar ||| This is a question and answer site and, although you didn't realize it was more complex than what you first though and, given that you probably might not have heard of star-delta transforms, we have to stick to the rules and not evolve questions too far. If SD transforms are confusing, ask a brand new question.

Comment: sorry I'm new here and don't know my way around very well. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's a two node circuit after suppressing the sources and connecting a test source between 1 and 2. Write the two node voltage equations and solve.

While the delta-star conversion will work I have a feeling most of us won't have it memorized.